# Valid Provisioning Profile not found for this device, Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

I started preparing my iOS app (Bruin Dining) for submission, but now when I try testing on my iphone, I receive the error, "Valid provisioning profile not found for this device."  I tried looking at other SO questions, but none of them were for Xcode 6.

Below are some screenshots of what I have in the developer portal.  Also, I verified that my iphone was listed as one of the devices usable for the app.

Some strange behavior I noticed:

When I tried creating a distribution profile with the name "Bruin Dining," I received an error along the lines of "Provisioning profile already exists with this name," so I ended up naming it "BruinDining." Also, when I double clicked on the "Bruin_Dining.mobileprovision" file, it didn't prompt me to "add to library".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your project settings show that you're using the distribution provisioning profile to compile your debug app on your phone. Try using your development profile when compiling in debug, it should work if the device you use is registered in it.

For your provisioning profile naming problem, you may want to name them "BruinDining_dev" and "BruinDining_distri" to make them obvious.

Comment: Ok, so it works now on my iphone 5, but now the screen is letterboxed and it shrunk to the iphone 4 size.  I'm wondering if this is a related problem?

Comment: No this is a different problem. Does your project contain a splashscreen image for iphone 5? When iPhone 5 was released, the system displayed as an iPhone 4 all applications without iPhone 5 sized splashscreen, maybe it is still the case.

Comment: I added an image to the launch image section of the image assets folder